# DocuSign "delete envelope lock" not working

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign REST API to automate document signing. I use the [sender view](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/) to allow my clients to place signing tabs on their documents and ultimately send them.

However, I'm running into a problem where the client, for whatever reason, needs to start over in our workflow, and so abandons the embed without saving it and contacting us to restart the process.

Normally, we'd call [Update](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/) to mark the Envelope as voided and then create a new one, but because the client didn't exit the embed properly, the Envelope is still marked as locked.

I thought the [Delete Lock](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeLocks/delete/) endpoint would allow us to remove the lock so that we could edit the envelope, but it's returning an error message saying that we can't delete the lock as we weren't the ones who put it there.

Given that the same credentials were used for both the embed window and the delete lock call, why does DocuSign treat us like two different users? And is there a way to get around the lock?

Comment: Its duplicate for [Envelope Lock by NDSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036596/docusign-api-discarding-within-sender-view-never-releases-edit-lock)

Comment: @AmitKBist That question seems to have been removed by it's author

Comment: Yeah I saw that

Comment: @AmitKBist link is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lock is done by NDSE not your credentials, solution is to wait for sometime and lock will be released by NDSE or you have to redirect user to same screen again and the user needs to select `Save and Close` instead of `Discard Changes`. Once user selects `Discard Changes` then envelope is moved to Deleted folder.

Comment: In the end, we used the embed's "completion" page to set a flag, and asked the user to please click "Save and Close" if they tried to leave the page without the flag set.

Answer (score 1):

This might help some folks in the future.

> "by appending a lockToken parameter to the view URL, you can give your
> integration control over the envelope lock, enabling it to make
> changes to the envelope without having to wait for the DocuSign token
> to expire."

http://m.mmffs.com/the-trenches-whos-locking-my-envelopes.html

The article shows how to accomplish this using the API directly. In the code snippet below, this is how you would do it going against the DocuSign Nuget package.

```
var lockInfo = envelopesApi.CreateLock(accountID, envelopeID, new LockRequest() 
{
    LockedByApp = "[Your App]",
    LockType = "edit"                 
});

existingViewUrl += "&lockToken={lockInfo.LockToken}";
```

Note, the third LockRequest parameter is required for this to work even though it is not required by the CreateLock method. Credit to Inbar Gazit - [Error trying to add a document to envelope and getting a user lock error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349613/error-trying-to-add-a-document-to-envelope-and-getting-a-user-lock-error-message)

Now, the normal DeleteLock method will work.

```
try
{
    var lockInfo = envelopesApi.GetLock(accountId, envelopeID);

    if (lockInfo?.LockDurationInSeconds?.Length > 0)
    {
        envelopesApi.ApiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Edit", $"{{\"lockToken\":\"{lockInfo.LockToken}\"}}");
        envelopesApi.DeleteLock(accountId, envelopeID);
    }
}
catch(ApiException e)
{
    // Not locked.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below:

```
var config = new Configuration(new ApiClient(basePath));
    config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);
    try
    {
       // this line will throw error if envelope is not locked, so handle it using try & catch block
       LockInformation lockInfo = envelopesApi.GetLock(accountId, envelopeId);

       // check if this app locked it
        if (lockInfo?.LockDurationInSeconds?.Length > 0)
       {
           // add a header with the LockToken to ensure this app has the right to unlock 
            string LockHeader = $"{{\"lockToken\":\"{lockInfo.LockToken}\"}}";
            envelopesApi.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Edit", LockHeader);
            envelopesApi.DeleteLock(accountId, envelopeId);
       }
    }
    catch (ApiException exp)
    {      
       // Do Whatever you want to do
       
    }
```