# Error trying to add a document to envelope and getting a user lock error message

Tags: docusignapi

I am having an issue trying to add an additional document to an existing draft envelope.

When i run the code below:

```
        public string AddDocuemnt(string envelopeID, string documentBase64, string filename, string extension, string documentID)
        {
            CheckToken();

            EnvelopesApi envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi(_apiClient.Configuration);
            EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();

            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.Name = filename;
            doc.DocumentBase64 = documentBase64;
            doc.DocumentId = documentID;
            doc.FileExtension = extension;

            envDef.Documents.Add(doc);

            EnvelopeDocumentsResult result =  envelopeApi.UpdateDocuments(AccountID, envelopeID, envDef);
            return result.ToJson();
        }
```

I get an "EDIT_LOCK_NOT_LOCK_OWNER" error.

```
{
  "errorCode": "EDIT_LOCK_NOT_LOCK_OWNER",
  "message": "The user is not the owner of the lock. The envelope is locked by another user or in another application"
}
```

I then added the following code before and after to try to create and then release a lock

```
envelopeApi.CreateLock(AccountID, envelopeID);

...Between code here...

envelopeApi.DeleteLock(AccountID, envelopeID);
```

I get the following error when it gets to the CreateLock call.

```
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY",
  "message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted."
}'
```

I have been searching google for the past hour to figure out how to successfully lock, update, and unlock an envelope.  I am not finding any help.

Can someone please assist?

Thanks
jlimited

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeLocks/create
Has the information.

When you call `CreateLock()` there's a third parameter with information you need to provide inside a `LockRequest` object. That has to be filled so that the API call can proceed.

Comment: So I added the LockRequest and it seems to lock the envelope.  I also added to my EnvelopeDefinition the LockInformation.  Now I am trying to submit the keep changes when I delete the lock...but the DeleteLock only takes the AccountID and EnvelopeID.

Comment: yes, that one is tricky, see here:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeLocks/delete
Doing this via the SDK will require some custom code to add the header.

Comment: I don't know if something changed on DocuSign's end but using DeleteLock with just the accountID and evenlopeID worked for me.  For the third parameter on the CreateLock method, I only specified the LockedByApp and LockType properties and that got  the job done.